# iOS 11: didExitRegion events are not being called reliably when monitoring beacons in the background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios11

I am trying to implement background region monitoring for iBeacons using iOS's CoreLocation API. I seem to get inconsistent results when exiting an iBeacon region which I have called "Entry/Exit Door". In the background, the app sometimes gets the didExitRegion event on time, sometimes it gets the didExitRegion event many minutes later, and other times it doesn't get the didExitRegion event at all. I'm not sure if there is something obvious that I am doing wrong? I attached my Swift class that I am implementing for iBeacon region monitoring below:

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BeaconRegionMonitor: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager
    var uuidDictionary:Dictionary<String, String> = ["Desks":"B0702880-A295-A8AB-F734-031A98A512DE", "Entry/Exit Door":"B0702880-A295-A8AB-F734-031A98A512DF"]

    required override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                stopMonitoringOldRegions()
                monitorUUIDS ()
                getInitialStatesForRegions()
            }
        }
    }

    func stopMonitoringOldRegions ()
    {
        let monitoredRegions = locationManager.monitoredRegions
        let uuidDictionaryIndenfiers = uuidDictionary.keys
        let oldMonitoredRegions = monitoredRegions.filter {!(uuidDictionaryIndenfiers.contains($0.identifier))}

        for oldMonitoredRegion in oldMonitoredRegions
        {
             NSLog("Stopped Monitoring \(oldMonitoredRegion.identifier)")
             locationManager.stopMonitoring(for : oldMonitoredRegion)
        }
    }

    func isRegionAlreadyBeingMonitored(regionToMonitor: CLRegion) -> Bool {
        let monitoredRegions = locationManager.monitoredRegions
        for region in monitoredRegions
        {
            if region.identifier == regionToMonitor.identifier
            {
                NSLog("Already Monitoring \(region.identifier)")
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func monitorUUIDS() {
        for identifierUuidPair in uuidDictionary
        {
            if let uuid = UUID(uuidString: identifierUuidPair.value) {
                let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(
                    proximityUUID: uuid,
                    identifier: identifierUuidPair.key)
                if !isRegionAlreadyBeingMonitored(regionToMonitor: beaconRegion)
                {
                    locationManager.startMonitoring(for : beaconRegion)
                    NSLog("Started Monitoring \(beaconRegion.identifier)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getInitialStatesForRegions ()
    {
        let monitoredRegions = locationManager.monitoredRegions
        for region in monitoredRegions
        {
            locationManager.requestState(for : region)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion){
        showLocalNotification("DER: Entered \(region.identifier)", alertAction: "")
        NSLog("DER: Entered \(region.identifier)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion){
        showLocalNotification("DXR: Exited \(region.identifier)", alertAction: "")
        NSLog("DXR: Exited \(region.identifier)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion){
        if region is CLBeaconRegion {
            if state == .inside {
                showLocalNotification("DDSR: Inside \(region.identifier)", alertAction: "")
                NSLog("DDSR: Inside \(region.identifier)")
            }
            else if state == .outside {
                showLocalNotification("DDSR: Outside \(region.identifier)", alertAction: "")
                NSLog("DDSR: Outside \(region.identifier)")
            }
            else {
                showLocalNotification("DDSR: Unknown \(region.identifier)", alertAction: "")
                NSLog("DDSR: State unknown for region \(region.identifier)")
            }
        }
    }

    func showLocalNotification(_ alertBody:String, alertAction:String) {
        scheduleLocalNotification(alertBody, alertAction: alertAction, fireDate: Date())
    }

    func scheduleLocalNotification(_ alertBody:String, alertAction:String, fireDate:Date){
        let alertBodyModified = alertBody.replacingOccurrences(of: "%", with: "%%")

        let settings = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings

        if settings?.types == .none {
            print("can't schedule notification")
            return
        }

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.fireDate = fireDate
        notification.alertBody = alertBodyModified
        notification.alertAction = alertAction
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }

}
```

Comment: It is common for `didExitRegion` events to lag when the app is in the background.  Are you sure that you *never* get the events?  How long do you wait?  I would wait 30 minutes before declaring that you never get them.  For troubleshooting purposes, I'd add `beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay-true` (make sure you delete your app and resinstall to make sure this takes effect) then look in the XCode debugger for a log message from  the `didDetermineState` callback.  Whenever you illuminate the display from a dark screen, this should get called and log the current inside/outside status.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your Swift response.

When I say the app _never_ gets the events, I'm describing a case where the app doesn't exit a region after hours of being outside the region. In this case, it seems as though the app only exits the region after reentering and then exiting the region hours later. FYI, I'm using an iPhone 6s running iOS 11 for testing purposes. 

Thanks, I will take your advice and try debugging using your troubleshooting recommendation. Hopefully it will shed some light on the issue.